# Get node name with minidom

Tags: python, minidom

Is it possible to get the name of a node using minidom?

For example I have a node:

```
<heading><![CDATA[5 year]]></heading>
```

What I'm trying to do, is store the value `heading` so that I can use it as a key in a dictionary.

The closest I can get is something like:

```
[<DOM Element: heading at 0x11e6d28>]
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something very simple here, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
tag= node.tagName
d[tag]= node
```

`tagName` is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614) in DOM Level 1 Core, the basic standard that minidom (mostly) implements.